# Limits to the possible scope of an answer - making a question invalid for Arqade

Tags: discussion

What is the limit to how large in scope an answer could be before a question is regarded to be too broad for Arqade and closed?

Eg. closing a question were the answer "might" be to large / broad.

Comment: Do you have an example of things you are thinking that *might* or *might not* be to broad?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8133/what-defines-a-question-as-being-too-broad-when-asking-about-easter-eggs)